# How many security guards were onboard D7-class starships?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, klingon

I understand that the answer will depend on the starship class, so since more specificity is required, I would say D7-class.

The reason is simple: in TOS era, at some point, the Klingons fought wars with D7-class ships. One would surmise that, at least in Klach D'Kel Brakt (DS9: Blood Oath), Klingons used boarding parties...

Comment: The complement of a modern Bird of Prey is thirty-six; http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/486.txt

Comment: And in the TOS era, it was about a dozen;  http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Trek/Star_Trek_III.htm

Comment: Obviously complements cannot be all security... what fraction of a ship's complement can reasonably be expected to be security?

Comment: If the current state of Klingon Defense Forces can be argued that it also existed way back when, then KDF forces were technically *all* security - every officer on board is a Warrior and can defend the ship to the death.  I'm not sure there's actually a 'security' complement on board when everyone is trained in military combat of all types as the standard regiment.   (rather than security centric training that Security personnel in the Federation would have, beyond standard combat training)

Answer (score 1):

According the the best available info (TOS: [Day of the Dove](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/66.htm)) the crew complement of a typical D-7 Klingon Cruiser is four hundred(ish).

> **KIRK:** *Maintain Red Alert.*
>
> (The Klingons arrive, and their leader hits Kirk with his disruptor,
>   knocking him down.)
>
> **KANG:** *You attacked my ship! **Four hundred of my crew dead.** Kirk, my ship is disabled. I claim yours. You are now prisoners of the
>   Klingon Empire against which you have committed a wanton act of war!*

At this point we're stuck with informed guesswork.

Since we know (courtesy of [Star Trek III](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Trek/Star_Trek_III.htm)) that the complement of the slightly smaller TOS-Era Bird of Prey is only "*about a dozen officers and men*", it stands to reason that the remainder of crew of the D-7 (**some 350 extra personnel**) are likely to be a mixture of boarding parties and security officers.